# Is it possible to control permissions on process substitution files?

Tags: bash, permissions, process-substitution

An email utility I often use has setuid permission, so as to be able to read some mail configuration files which are not publicly accessible.  In order to limit security concerns, the utility ownership is that of the mail user, not root.  So far so good.

Now I'm trying to pass an extra configuration file to the utility, using process substitution.  However, I get `Cannot read /dev/fd/63: Permission denied`.  How come?  It seems bash doesn't respect umask values:

```bash
ale@pcale:~/tmp$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
ale@pcale:~/tmp$ namei -l <(echo foo)
f: /dev/fd/63
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root dev
lrwxrwxrwx root root fd -> /proc/self/fd
drwxr-xr-x root root   /
dr-xr-xr-x root root   proc
lrwxrwxrwx root root   self -> 25980
dr-xr-xr-x ale  ale      25980
dr-x------ ale  ale    fd
lr-x------ ale  ale  63 -> pipe:[58230201]
                       pipe:[58230201] - No such file or directory
```

The obvious workaround is to run such scripts as the mail user as well.  However, out of curiosity, what's that?  A bug?  A feature?

Comment: I don't understand your need: `read < <(echo foo);echo $REPLY` return *foo*. Did you make some `sudo` ? What is the command you run, wich return *permisionm denied*?

Comment: Is your problem similar to this? `su some_other_user -c 'cat '<(echo)` `cat: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied`

Comment: @Fravadona Yes, except for the `su` part.  The called program is setuid.  I thought the first paragraph was clear.  Shall I post an example?

Comment: @Ale the program that is suid will run as an other; unless it is root, it won't have the right to access the current script environment

Comment: @Fravadona so one can derive a rule that setuid programs _must_ be owned by root, with many greetings to security concerns...?

Comment: @Ale no, just generate a real file that's readable by the suid user; or feed the content of the file through stdin

Comment: @Fravadona yup, I did so.  It's a pity, because process-substitution would have made it pretty self-contained.  However, `/proc/self/fd` itself is only accessible to its owner, so I don's think bash could do better even if it wanted.

Comment: @Ale If the suid command accepts input from stdin instead of a file then you could just do `echo foo | suidCommand`

Comment: @Fravadona no, suid is in the executable file permissions.  Even if you're root, it's unsafe to change the executable's ownership or permissions just for the current call.  Perhaps could mount an alias as nosuid and then call one or the other, but it sounds over complicated.